How Could Jasypt Encrypt full yaml file without mvn
How i could tell jasypt encrypt all "DEC()" strings in application.yml file without maven command?
I know what mvn plugin could do it with command :
mvn jasypt:encrypt "-Djasypt.encryptor.password=password"

And All DEC() Strings in application.yml become
DEC(123) -> ENC(95yNXWtl4wwobyDzRFy+jydcvBERJWWx)

But how do it without mvn command, just with spring boot? I can't find any information about it.
